# Pulling multiple elements from dataframe R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

```
team    id  name
1   2335    Victor
1   379 Marc
1   4484    Newton
2   51  AZRIA
2   379 Marc
2   552 Steve
2   1674    Miu
2   1688    Moschi
```

edit to make more clear:

1. Say given team 1, how can I return all the ids with team 1?
2. should i use a for loop to go through all through all teams?

Comment: It sounds like you want multiple things. The first part is just `df[df$team==1,]`, etc. It's unclear what exactly the next parts of your question are asking for.

Comment: `df[df$team == 1, "id"]` or `df$id[df$team == 1]` this is very basic R so you have to go through tutorial http://www.statmethods.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you each team as a separate dataframe in a list:

```
split(df, df$team)
```

It sounds like your `id` and `name` variables do not vary (i.e., that `id` and `name` are basically identical). In that case, to find the most common `id` or `name`, just use `table` (possibly `sort`-ed):

```
sort(table(df$id), decreasing=TRUE)
sort(table(df$name), decreasing=TRUE)
```

You might also want something like to combine the two:

```
sort(with(df, table(paste(id,name))),decreasing=TRUE)
```

Comment: Yeah, also is there a way to find the most common teamid in  the teams? In my example. 379 Marc appears in 2 teams. How can I find the top 5 most popular team members?

Comment: however, not all teams are the same size so i am not sure if table would work. I was thinking of just extracting all the elements of a list and finding the most common element

Comment: and this is after I filtered down the list

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for, I guess. You want the most common id across all teams? (That's my answer) Or something else? And how does that depend on team size?

Comment: Use `split(df, df$team)` instead of `apply(unique(df$team), function(x) df[df$team==x,])`.

Comment: That's definitely the way to go!